# How can I share my shopping cart with someone else on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

How can I share my shopping cart with someone else on Amazon?

I know I can click on "save for later" and then add each item to a wish list that I can share, but is there a more direct way to share my shopping cart?

Comment: Hey! I've built a Chrome extension to make it easy to share your Amazon cart — [Share your Amazon cart in 1 click](https://amzcartshare.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't directly share your shopping cart directly, I mean you can't share links of your cart by anyway because of security.
So most usual and used way to do that is by sharing your 'wish list' or you can use an extension like
[Shopping Cart Share For Amazon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopping-cart-share/apnigoloonhabnplobkhailjllggdnll)

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue recently and didn't find a solution. So, I made a cart sharing extension for Chrome browser. Here you go: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-share-a-cart/peiobddfomnijgoblelfdmjblplojcoe